# Is there a keyboard shortcut for accessing the the Widget Configure settings in an Azure DevOps Dashboard?

Tags: azure-devops, widget, keyboard-shortcuts, dashboard

I need to figure out the shortcut keys for accessing the most recent widget's configure settings. I have looked at the official Microsoft documents for Azure and did not find anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no keyboard shortcut for the Widget Configure settings, you could submit a user voice at website below:

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/report?space=21&entry=suggestion